# Why does Jetpack Compose provide separate button types like OutlinedButton, TextButton and Button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Why does Jetpack Compose provide separate button types like `OutlinedButton` and `TextButton`, instead of passing the button style as a parameter to a single Button type?

I understand that this will help us in better code organization and maintainability, and also make it easier to understand the purpose of the components from the name directly, rather than a generic name with a bunch of parameters!

**This question** isn't just about buttons, but this design decision of why Jetpack Compose offers multiple composable functions for different visual styles, rather than providing a single base composable function that can be customized with style parameters.

Because in the end, if we see the code of these components, you will see it is calling the base components with just different parameters:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OutlinedButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.outlinedShape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = null,
    border: BorderStroke? = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonBorder,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) =
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = modifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        shape = shape,
        colors = colors,
        elevation = elevation,
        border = border,
        contentPadding = contentPadding,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        content = content
    )
```

Comment: Always add code instead of screenshoot of the code. I have added the code from your screenshoot.

Comment: Jetpack Compose provides separate button types for better user experience, code organization, and easier understanding of the component's purpose.

Separate button types allow developers to use the appropriate button style and customize it further as needed, following the principle of separation of concerns in software design.

Answer (score 1):

Material design components exist not only for Compose, but for Views, Web, Flutter, and as a design principle.

Because of that they are not just styles but Components with each own guidelines, rationale and purposes to create a design style with both M2 and M3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://m3.material.io/components/all-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just because Jetpack Compose like other frontend technologies implement the material UI language which offer all those kinds of buttons.